# print multiple histograms to a pdf in R

Tags: r, histogram

I'm looking for a way to print a list of histograms to a PDF in `R`.

I've found a bunch of ways to do it for `ggplot2` plots, but none for `histograms`. I am using the `base` histogram functions.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. How exactly do you want this plots be be arranged? How many do you have?

Comment: Also, are you aware that ggplot2 and histograms don't contradict each other? ggplot can take a plethora of form, for example histograms.

Comment: @Georgery - I was not aware, thanks for the info. The few samples applicable to ggplot2 did not work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, just in case ggplot could be an alternative:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
    b = rnorm(10000)
    , c = 1:10000
)

df %>%
    ggplot(aes(b)) +
    geom_histogram()
```

The [R Graphics Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/) helps. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For `base` graphics, use `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` for example.  If you print more than 4 plots, it will flow over into a new page, if you are using the `pdf` graphics output.